# Any way to extend the line in the legend?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Let us say I have the following graph plotted using ggplot:

[image]

Is there anyway to extend how much line length is displayed in the legend? Sometimes, it just gets impossible to identify which line correspond to which line in the graph using the legend.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

here is an option `legend.key.width`:

```
# sample data frame
df <- data.frame(x = c(rnorm(100, -3), rnorm(100), rnorm(100, 3)), 
                 g = gl(3, 100))
df <- ddply(df, .(g), summarize, x = x, y = ecdf(x)(x))

ggplot(df, aes(x, y, colour = g, linetype = g)) + 
    geom_line() + 
    theme(legend.key.width = unit(10, "line"))
```

[image]

Comment: is there a new option for this answer?  doesn't seem to work in ggplot v3.4.4

Answer (score 0):

`opts` is not working with *ggplot2*. You need to use `theme`, so instead you need to type:

```
+ theme(legend.key.width = unit(10, "line"))
```